# How to determine if two quaternion has same orientation

Tags: quaternions

For example these two quaternions q1 = [0.905, -0.426, 0, 0] and q2 = [1, 0, 0, 0] must have same orientation. But how to determine if they really do?

I am well aware that there is another topic about [degree between two quaternion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/quaternion-distance) but this is a completely different question.

Edited: change to correct link

Comment: Sorry, the link should be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/quaternion-distance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you can do a component wise check q1 = q2 or q1 = -q2.

Here is some code that does this.

```ts
function approximatelyEqual(n1: number, n2: number, epsilon: number): boolean {
  return Math.abs(n1 - n2) < epsilon;
}

class Quaternion {
  w: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;

  constructor(w: number, x: number, y: number, z: number) {
      this.w = w;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.z = z;
  }

  isEqual(other: Quaternion, epsilon: number): boolean {
    return (
      approximatelyEqual(this.w, other.w, epsilon) &&
      approximatelyEqual(this.x, other.x, epsilon) &&
      approximatelyEqual(this.y, other.y, epsilon) &&
      approximatelyEqual(this.z, other.z, epsilon)
    ) || (
      approximatelyEqual(this.w, -other.w, epsilon) &&
      approximatelyEqual(this.x, -other.x, epsilon) &&
      approximatelyEqual(this.y, -other.y, epsilon) &&
      approximatelyEqual(this.z, -other.z, epsilon)
    )
  }
}

// ApproximatelyEqual ensures two numbers are equal within a certain tolerance.
// this gives some "wiggle room" when working with floating point numbers.

console.log(approximatelyEqual(1, 1, 0.01)) // true
console.log(approximatelyEqual(1, 1.001, 0.01)) // true
console.log(approximatelyEqual(1, 1.1, 0.01)) // false

// Quaternions are equal when all components are the same or opposite.
const q1 = new Quaternion(1, 2, 3, 4);
const q2 = new Quaternion(-1, -2, -3, -4);
const q3 = new Quaternion(0, 1, 2, 3);

console.log(q1.isEqual(q1, 0.01)) // true
console.log(q1.isEqual(q2, 0.01)) // true
console.log(q1.isEqual(q3, 0.01)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

To correct your answer.

1. If you take 3d vector, for example, on "Z"  axis, and quaternion rotates around Z axis, than you'll detect empty rotation. but it can rotate even with 180 degree around Z.
2. You need exactly "angle between quaternions". Answer is here ["Distance" (or angular magnitude) between two quaternions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260939/distance-or-angular-magnitude-between-two-quaternions)

Answer (score -1):

I found out the answer.

Just apply the quaternion to a 3-D vector. If the final result from q1 and q2 is the same, then the quaternion has "same direction".

Also, I misunderstood the meaning of quaternion. Quaternion is an apply of rotation, it does not have orientation.

Comment: FYI quaternions are pretty commonly used to demonstrate orientation by inertial measurement units (IMUs). Just like you did, to get your orientation you apply the quaternion rotation to the original or North facing vector

Comment: In my opinion, this is a pretty inefficient way of checking for equality. You have to pick an non-arbitrary vector and do an expensive operation.