# How to find the angle between two rotational quaternions?

Tags: python, quaternions, coordinate-systems, euler-angles

[image: Sample Dataset]

I want to find out by much angle each quaternion is moving and if its rotating in the same direction ( clockwise / anti-clockwise)

Right now, I am doing the following to calculate the rotation but I am not sure if its correct.

```
def quaternion_angle(q1, q2):
    dot_product = np.dot(q1, q2)
    # Ensure dot product is within -1 and 1 for arccos
    dot_product = np.clip(dot_product, -1.0, 1.0)
    return np.arccos(dot_product) * 2 * 180/np.pi  # convert to degrees
```

Comment: look at answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260939/distance-or-angular-magnitude-between-two-quaternions/23263233#23263233

Comment: @minorlogic i forgot it add that i have rotational quaternions. Is the process different for rotational quaternions?

Comment: The answer above for rotational quaternions

Comment: And how to calculate the the direction of the rotation? if its a clockwise or anticlockwise rotation?